# Issues with Peeking and Popping

Tags: ios, swift

I am building a contact app in Xcode 9, Swift 4, iOS 11 but I am having a tough time attempting to implement Peek and Pop into my application. Here's how it's supposed to work: The user is presented with their list of contacts on a UITableView. I want the user to be able to use 3D Touch to peek at a contact without having to open the contact and pop it if they wish to open the contact. I found a great tutorial at [Techotopia](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_9_3D_Touch_Peek_and_Pop_Tutorial) on using 3D Touch but haven't been able to get it to work. Xcode is not giving me any errors, yet when I debug the app on my iPhone 8, it does not work. Here is my code:

```
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location),
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else {
            return nil }

    guard let detailViewController =
        storyboard?.instantiateViewController(
            withIdentifier: "InfoContactController") as?
        InfoContactController else { return nil }

    detailViewController.preferredContentSize =
        CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 600)

    previewingContext.sourceRect = cell.frame

    return detailViewController
}

func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
    show(viewControllerToCommit, sender: self)
}
```

In the tutorial at Techotopia, they use this code in `viewDidLoad` to register the previewing delegate:

```
if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available {
    registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: view)
} else {
    print("3D Touch Not Available")
}
```

The above code prints "3D Touch Not Available" in my console although I was obviously using a 3D Touch capable device. So, I did some research on Google and found this code which works:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    switch traitCollection.forceTouchCapability {
    case .available:
        print("Available")
    case .unavailable:
        print("Unavailable")
    case .unknown:
        print("Unknown")
    }
}
```

This is my code. It gives me no errors in Xcode but when I 3D Touch in the app, nothing happens and I do not know why.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just making sure that in your actual code you do call `registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: view)` in the new code you found on Google when the `.available` case is met?

Comment: I think `traitCollectionDidChange` won't fire when the view is added to the hierarchy.  You could try checking on `viewWillAppear` but I personally just do `registerForPreviewing` without the if statement.  It's not called for in the docs.

Comment: @Popmedic I'm not clear what you are asking. If you are asking if "Available" is printed to the console when this code is executed, then yes.

Comment: @BrianNickel I'll give your suggestion a shot.

Comment: @NathanaelCarper, @Popmedic is saying that in your "final" code you missed to actually call `registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: view)` when `Available` is printed in the console.

Comment: @MihaiFratu Ohhhhhhh, thanks for the clarification. It's partially working now! I can use peek and pop on the first contact in my table view. I'll have to play with it and get it to completely work. Wow, that was a dumb mistake. Thanks so much @Popmedic!

Comment: I only ask cause I have done it before, once or twice ;-)

Comment: @Popmedic Haha, well its a first for me and not likely a last. Thanks again!

Comment: Unless you are planning alternative behaviour don't bother checking for 3D touch support.  Just call registerForPreviewing.  It does not cause an error and works just fine.